# "Наш" і "наший"

Tags: граматика, займенники

Я українка, і я помітила, що є люди, які говорять **"наш"** і які говорять **"наший"**.  Який варіант більш граматично правильний?

Answer (score 8):

***Наш*** — нормативне (зокрема [див. у «Словнику української мови» в 11 томах](http://sum.in.ua/s/nash)).

***Наший*** — діалектне, зокрема західнополіське (в словниках зазвичай відсутнє):

> Серед присвійних займенників виділяються форми *на́ший* 'наш' і *ва́ший* 'ваш', що виникли за аналогією до інших займенників із закінченнями *-ий* || *-ій* (*са́мий*, *йі́хн'ій*, *вс'а́кий*) та до повних форм прикметників чоловічого роду: *на́ший куто́к*, *на́ший ба́т'ушка*, *ва́ший брат*, *де ва́ший па́рубок?*..
>   <sub>[Г. Аркушин, «Іменний словотвір західнополіського говору», Луцьк, «Вежа», 2004, ISBN 966-600-145-4, с. 701](//books.google.com/books?id=sgcaAQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%88%22).</sub>

Також є форма *наши́й* у дієслова *нашива́ти*.

Comment: Дякую за відповідь.  А що більш формальне?

Comment: @Ксеничка, «наш».